# Firefox App tabs on the right side

Tags: firefox

You know how when you pin a tab as an app tab, it minimizes into a small square tab and is anchored to the very left of the tab section? Is it possible to make it so the app tab is anchored to the very right instead? Like right next to the minimize, maximize, close buttons.

Comment: I wish there was. I stop noticing pinned tabs on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As the New tab button is on the right side and new tabs also open from there, it is more usable for the user if the tabs are fixed at the extreme left. So that user can browse more conveniently between the group of fixed tabs and the new and temporary tabs.

Comment: It is likely possible with some CSS magic, since Firefox uses XUL for it's GUI.